How to include a package with a different name with python-poetry?
I have a multi-language project, say project, and I want to organize language-specific libraries in src/ like this
.
├── pyproject.toml
└── src
├── idl
└── python

where src/python/ is the python package that should be installed by poetry.
In pyproject.toml, I would include src/python/ via
[tool.poetry]
packages = [
    { include = "python", from = "src" }
]

Then the python library can be imported in a python environment
>>> import python

But I want the importable library to be named project instead of python. How do I change the name of the importable library without renaming src/python to src/project?
